# Shiny observer - how to use observer to update global variables?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

How can I update the global variable using observer?

I have an empty species on start:

```
speciesChoices <- c()
```

But I want to add values into it when something has changed on the ui, so it becomes:

```
speciesChoices <- c(
    'PM2.5' = 'particles'
)
```

Is it possible?

My code so far...

ui.r:

```
speciesOptions <- selectInput(
    inputId = "species",
    label = "Species:",
    choices = c(
        # 'PM2.5' = 'particles',
        # 'Humidity %' = 'humidity'
    )
)
```

server.r:

```
speciesChoices <- c() # global variable

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

   observe({
        key <- input$streams1

        stream <- fromJSON(paste(server, "/output/stream?public_key=", key, sep=""),flatten=TRUE)
        species <- as.data.frame(stream$species)

        # Set choices of title and code for select input.
        speciesChoices <- setNames(species$code_name, species$public_name)

        updateSelectInput(session, "species", choices = speciesChoices)
    })

})
```

It only update the input on the ui but not the speciesChoices on the server.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use something like `speciesChoices <<- setNames(input$species$code_name, input$species$public_name)`. You need both the super-assign operator `<<-` to change a global variable, and you need to use `input$_id_` to refer to inputs set in the ui.

Side note: I'm not sure what your endgame is here, but make sure that you actually want to be using an observer and not a reactive. For an idea of the difference between these, see [Joe Cheng's slides from useR2016](https://github.com/jcheng5/user2016-tutorial-shiny/blob/master/slides.Rmd#takeaway-takeaway).